# Polynomial root of algebraic number

Tags: polynomials, definition, roots, algebraic-numbers

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), an algebraic number is any complex number (including real numbers) that is a root of a non-zero polynomial in one variable with rational coefficients.

The polynomial has many roots, how do I know which of the roots does the algebraic number denotes?

Is this where e.g. "isolating interval representation" comes in, that is, I need to somehow bound which root I'm interested in? What other ways there are to identify a given root?

As you could surely tell, I'm very new to this kind of math...

Comment: All the roots are algebraic.  Phrased differently, $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ is algebraic iff $\exists \{\lambda_i\}_{i=0}^n\in \mathbb Q$, not all $0$,  such that $\sum \lambda_i\alpha^i=0$.

Comment: For $n$-th order polynomial, in general, all roots have the equal footings.  However, an algebraic number has a minimal polynomial defining itself.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672795/difference-between-i-and-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows directly from the definition that *every* root of a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients is an algebraic number.

Comment: What confuses me is that when I try to visualise it, two real roots are at different distances from the zero, so I though the two algebraic "numbers" means these two distances. So the right way to think about an algebraic number is that it denotes all the distances from zero at the same time?

Comment: @Faaf They have nothing to do with distances. Take $-\sqrt2$, for instance. Or $i$. Both of them are algebraic, but none of them is a distance.

Comment: Yes, I meant real roots. But the point is, that one algebraic number represent all the roots, not just one root, correct?

Comment: @Faaf Wong. **Each** root is an algebraic number. For instance, $x^2+1$ has $2$ roots: $i$ and $-i$. Therefore, each one of them is an algebraic number.

Comment: I'm very sorry for being slow on this one, but this is where I get confused. Ok, both $i$ and $-i$ are algebraic numbers. But since they are the roots of the same minimal polynomial, how to distinguish between them? My original question was, given $x^2+1$, how do I "talk" about $i$, instead of $-i$?

Comment: @Faaf $\operatorname{Im}(i)=1$, whereas $\operatorname{Im}(-i)=-1$. That's a difference between them, right?! I admit that they are impossible to distinguish algebraically (in the sense that whenever one of them is a root of a polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients, then the other one is also a root of $P(x)$), but I don't see why that's a problem for you.

Comment: Let's say I would like to add two algebraic numbers. Apart from the problem of computing the resulting minimal polynomial, how do I know which root of the final polynomial is the result? Does it even make sense to ask such a question?

Comment: What I mean is in order to know which exact root I would like to talk about, I need some extra machinery to denote it, in addition to the minimal polynomial, correct? And that machinery could be an interval with rational endpoints or something else? But just the minimal polynomial is not enough. So I can say that $i$ is algebraic number because it is a root of $x^2+1$ but not the other way around: just knowing the minimal polynomial is not enough to know I talk about $i$, instead of $-i$. Correct? Sorry, does it make sense?

Comment: @Faaf Double yes: it makes sense and just knowing the minimal polynomial is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood them correctly,

1. Each algebraic number has a unique minimal polynomial.
2. More than one algebraic number may have the same minimal polynomial. The set of numbers having the same minimal polynomial are the roots of that polynomial.

One method of identifying the boundaries in the complex plane that contain a given root of a minimal polynomial is the [Kollins-Crandick algorithm](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0898122199003363/1-s2.0-S0898122199003363-main.pdf?_tid=0830b0f8-75f3-41c7-8748-c7de88717fdd&acdnat=1521477906_c30ba9526eeee9339b3681b3ab0d7825).

Those rectangles provide a means of uniquely identifying which root of the minimal polynomial you are interested in once the rectangles have been refined enough to be disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic numbers that are roots of the same minimal polynomial are indistinguishable algebraically: There is always an automorphism of the field of algebraic numbers that interchanges them. However, these automorphisms are not order automorphisms, therefore you can tell algebraic numbers apart by comparing them using the ordering of the rational numbers, *if* you can induce an ordering on the algebraic numbers from that. To do this, you don't have to explicitly specify for each possible minimal polynomial the ordering of its roots in a way that consistently turns the algebraic numbers into an ordered superfield of the rationals. You can specify a root using rational numbers to specify an interval, or for complex numbers a circle/rectangle, that contains exactly one root of the minimal polynomial. This of course means you have to be able to tell whether such an interval/rectangle/circle contains a single root, [and there are algorithms for that]. Note that the number of roots in an interval is independent from the concrete ordering of the algebraic numbers.